# Only show non-default attributes in repr of attr.s class

Tags: python-attrs

I'm using [attrs](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/index.html) to define simple classes without boilerplate code. The decorator automatically generates a `__repr__` that shows the values for all attributes. I'd like to only show attributes that do not have their default values:

```
>>> import attr
>>> @attr.s
... class Coordinates(object):
...     x = attr.ib(default=0)
...     y = attr.ib(default=0)
>>> Coordinates()  # wanted output: Coordinates()
Coordinates(x=0, y=0)
>>> Coordinates(x=0, y=0)  # wanted output: Coordinates()
Coordinates(x=0, y=0)
>>> Coordinates(x=1)  # wanted output: Coordinates(x=1)
Coordinates(x=1, y=0)
>>> Coordinates(x=1, y=1)  # output OK
Coordinates(x=1, y=1)
```

Is there any reasonably easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there’s not and it’s also a fairly specific request. :)  People have been asking for more ways to customise `repr`’s output by passing e.g. callable so that might make your use case easier, once it lands.  However I’m not aware of anyone actively working on that right now.

Comment: Thanks for the response! More customization of `repr` would definitely be great. For the time being, the custom class decorator covers my particular need.

Answer (score 2):

You'll definitely need to provide your own `__repr__` for that scenario.  Don't forget to set `repr=False` in the class decorator (hopefully that will be unnecessary in the future, see https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/324).

Answer (score 1):

```py
# requires python >= 3.8 (walrus operator)
def repr_without_defaults(cls):
    def __repr__(self):
        content = ", ".join( [f"{a.name}={v!r}" for a in self.__attrs_attrs__ if (v := getattr(self, a.name)) != a.default] )
        return f"{type(self).__name__}({content})"
    cls.__repr__ = __repr__
    return cls
```

(derived from @MichaelGoerz's answer, but much shorter)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a way, with the following class decorator:

```py
def no_default_vals_in_repr(cls):
    """Class decorator on top of attr.s that omits attributes from srepr that
    have their default value"""

    defaults = OrderedDict()
    for attribute in cls.__attrs_attrs__:
        defaults[attribute.name] = attribute.default

    def repr_(self):
        real_cls = self.__class__
        qualname = getattr(real_cls, "__qualname__", None)
        if qualname is not None:
            class_name = qualname.rsplit(">.", 1)[-1]
        else:
            class_name = real_cls.__name__
        attributes = defaults.keys()
        return "{0}({1})".format(
            class_name,
            ", ".join(
                name + "=" + repr(getattr(self, name))
                for name in attributes
                if getattr(self, name) != defaults[name]))

    cls.__repr__ = repr_
    return cls
```

This results in the following correct behavior:

```py
>>> @no_default_vals_in_repr
... @attr.s
... class Coordinates(object):
...     x = attr.ib(default=0)
...     y = attr.ib(default=0)
>>> Coordinates()
Coordinates()
>>> Coordinates(x=0, y=0)
Coordinates()
>>> Coordinates(x=1)
Coordinates(x=1)
>>> Coordinates(x=1, y=1)
Coordinates(x=1, y=1)
```